# No instance for (Num (Maybe a0)) arising from a use of ‘it’

Tags: haskell

I am trying to do a simplest thing in `ghci` console. I want to be able to have values of type `[Maybe Int]`. But either `Nothing : [1, Nothing]` or `[1, Nothing] ++ [Nothing]` gives an error that I find difficult to understand:

```
No instance for (Num (Maybe a0)) arising from a use of ‘it’
    In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Could please someone explain this error and suggest how to fix it?

Comment: `[1,Nothing]`? In Haskell a list contains only one type of elements.

Comment: I want to be able to have values of type `[Maybe Int]`. Do I have to explicitly specify it?

Comment: You need to wrap `1` in the `Just` constructor (`Just 1`). `Nothing` isn't the same as like `null` in other languages it's just an empty constructor for `Maybe`.

Comment: @ryachza: of course! this is so obvious to me now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer**: you probably want to write `[Just 1,Nothing]`.

**Explanation**:

In Haskell, a **list can contain only one type of elements**. So you can not mix for instance `Int`s and `String`s in the same list.

If you write:

```
[1, Nothing]
```

Haskell will aim to derive the type. Since you have written a `Nothing`, Haskell derives that the list contains elements of type `Maybe a` (it does not know which `a`). Now it wants to convert `1` to a `Maybe a`. Numeric literals can be converted to any class `n` with typeclass `Num n`. But there is no `a` for which `Maybe a` is `Num (Maybe a)`, so Haskell will error on this.

You can however use `Just 1` since Haskell will then derive that the `a` of `Maybe a` has typeclass `Num a`:

```
Prelude> :t [Just 1,Nothing]
[Just 1,Nothing] :: Num a => [Maybe a]
```

Answer (score 7):

In Haskell, lists (that is, things of type `[a]` for some `a`) can only contain values of a single type (`a`).

Haskell also has polymorphic numeric literals, so the error would be slightly clearer if we restricted the type of `1`:

```
λ Nothing : [1 :: Int, Nothing]

<interactive>:1:12: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe a’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the expression: 1 :: Int
      In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘[1 :: Int, Nothing]’
      In the expression: Nothing : [1 :: Int, Nothing]
    • Relevant bindings include
        it :: [Maybe a] (bound at <interactive>:1:1)
```

`Nothing` is of type `Maybe a`, `1 :: Int` is of type `Int`. The type checker can't find a way
to make `Maybe a` and `Int` the same type, so it reports an error.

If you want to have a list of some values and some `Nothing`s, you need to use `Maybe a`'s `Just` constructor:

```
Just :: a -> Maybe a
```

So you'd do this:

```
λ Nothing : [ Just 1, Nothing ]
[Nothing,Just 1,Nothing]
```